# Android AudioRecord return twice more data on read

Tags: android, pcm, audiorecord

I have strange situation with recording on Android. I created AudioRecorder with sample rate 8kHz, Mono, PCM 16 bit. But when i call read, it return twice more samples that needed. For example i rite 2 seconds on microphone, which must give 16k samples, but instead it gives 32k samples.

the code running in thread and pretty simple:

```
numSamples = audioRecord.read(buf, 0, SIMPLE_RECORDER_BUFFER_SIZE);
writer.write(stereo, 0, numSamples)
```

Does anyone had this issue?